# Building a TreeView issue

Tags: c#, treeview, kendo-treeview

I'm trying to build a `treeViewItemModel` with 3 levels, that may or not exist.

Like this:

[image: Tree]

From a webservice, I get an object that contains **segments**, each one has information about the **characteristic** and **direction** to which it belongs. But I can't seem to find a way to build a tree in the above structure.

Here's the point I'm at right now:

```
foreach (wsPAVSegment.segmentOutput segment in gso.segments)
{
    if (!characteristicList.Contains(segment.characteristic.code))
    {
        characteristicList.Add(segment.characteristic.code);
        characteristicTree.Add(new TreeViewItemModel
        {
            Id = segment.characteristic.code,
            Text = segment.characteristic.mediumDescription
        });
    }
}

foreach (wsPAVSegment.segmentOutput segment in gso.segments)
{
    foreach (TreeViewItemModel item in characteristicTree)
    {
        if (item.Id == segment.characteristic.code)
        {
            TreeViewItemModel tvim = new TreeViewItemModel();
            tvim.Id = segment.segment.id;
            tvim.Text = segment.segment.code;

            item.Items.Add(tvim);
        }
    }
}

foreach (wsPAVSegment.segmentOutput segment in gso.segments)
{
    if (!directionList.Contains(segment.direction.code))
    {
        directionList.Add(segment.direction.code);
        directionTree.Add(new TreeViewItemModel
        {
            Id = segment.direction.code,
            Text = segment.direction.mediumDescription,
            Items = characteristicTree
        });
    }
}

fullTree = directionTree;
```

The result is a tree with only one root that corresponds to a direction, and the characteristics in it are correct, as well as the segments inside the characteristics.

Can someone help?

Comment: do you forced to do the above structure in your way??because I don't understand your way but I have another way that help you to achieve the above tree structure

Comment: Thank you for your comment @FerasSalim. Meanwhile, I found a solution, I answered my own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by duplicating the winning formula I had. As stated in the question `The result is a tree with only one root that corresponds to a direction, and the characteristics in it are correct, as well as the segments inside the characteristics.`

I opted to have two trees, one below the other, one for each direction. Problem solved.